# Jquery droppable with knockout - how to cancel from within "drop"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have the following:

```
$(".subject-box").droppable({
        // revert: "invalid",
        activeClass: 'subject-box-active',
        hoverClass: 'subject-box-hover',
        accept: ".subject-box, .class-box",
        tolerance: 'intersect',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            dropItem(ko.dataFor(ui.draggable.context), ko.dataFor(this));
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#container').isotope('remove', ui.draggable);
            }, 0); 

        }
    });
```

So I accept anything with a css class of `.subject-box` or `.class-box`, and then call `dropItem` when an item is dropped.  dropItem is here:

```
var dropItem = function(item, parent) {
    // do some evaluation of the item (dragged) and parent (accepts item being dragged)
    // possible cancel based on values of item or parent
    return;
};
```

This gives me access to the `item` and `parent` objects so I can perform some evaluation, which is working as expected, but I need to cancel the drop action if some properties of the parent object are true - specifically, auth related properties.

How can I either cancel the drop action from within `drop:`, or give `accept:` access to the parent and child items to perform the evaluation there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

It will accept your drop and if you want to cancel it then use `return false` in it.

Answer (score 1):

something to consider when designing how your viewmodels interact with your UI is the use of custom bindings.  these enable you to reuse this type of logic in a more generic way across your application, and offers greater flexibility for what you are trying to do in this example.

I was able to find this series of blog posts where someone has developed a custom binding to handle the jquery ui drag/drop features:

- http://wilsonhut.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/knockout-jqueryui-draggabledroppable/
- http://wilsonhut.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/knockout-jquery-ui-draggabledroppable-follow-up/
- http://wilsonhut.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/knockout-jqueryui-draggabledroppable-the-end/
- Github source - https://github.com/wilsonhut/knockoutjs-drag-n-drop

for your case, you could do something like this (snippet from the above source)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.drop = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var dropElement = $(element);
        var dropOptions = {
            tolerance: 'pointer',

            // add whatever other options here
            accept: function () {
                // check if the element has the right classes
                if (!dropElement.hasClass("subject-box") && !dropElement.hasClass("class-box")) {
                    return false;
                }
                // get reference to current and parent contexts

                // contains the parent context of current binding context
                var parent = bindingContext.$parent;

                // current context (item)
                var item = viewModel;

                // add logic here to determine if item is allowable based on current and parent viewmodels

            }, 
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                _hasBeenDropped = true;
                valueAccessor().value(_dragged);
                ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revertDuration", 0);
            }
        };
        dropElement.droppable(dropOptions);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var dropElement = $(element);
        var disabled = !! ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor().disabled);
        dropElement.droppable("option", "accept", disabled ? ".nothing" : "*");
    }
};
```